# Loading external script with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2

I want to attach this script : http://findify-assets-2bveeb6u8ag.netdna-ssl.com/search/prod/beatmed.com.min.js with RequireJS, but It destroys other scripts from require.

My  js config:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "findify": "//findify-assets-2bveeb6u8ag.netdna-ssl.com/search/prod/beatmed.com.min",
        "test": "////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min"
    },
}
require.config(config);
```

In HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['findify']);
</script>
```

I have problem with the findify script, the "test" loads without errors in console.

Console Errors:

[image]

[image]

This script loads also other files for example: beatmed.com.min.js

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the findify script below, you can see that it overrides the requirejs implementation `require` and can therefore not find its `exec` function anymore.
So findify is loaded correctly, but then requirejs is gone!

**Findify-script excerpt**

```
require = function a(b, c, d) {
    function e(g, h) {
        if (!c[g]) {
            if (!b[g]) {
                var i = "function" == typeof require && require;
                if (!h && i) return i(g, !0);
                if (f) return f(g, !0);
                var j = new Error("Cannot find module '" + g + "'");
                throw j.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", j
            }
            var k = c[g] = {
                exports: {}
            };
            b[g][0].call(k.exports, function(a) {
                var c = b[g][1][a];
                return e(c ? c : a)
            }, k, k.exports, a, b, c, d)
        }
        return c[g].exports
    }
    for (var f = "function" == typeof require && require, g = 0; g < d.length; g++) e(d[g]);
    return e
}({..........
....
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I still don't know what to do with this information. Have you go any idea?

Comment: That's another question. Don't know what findify is used for.
But you can ask [here](https://github.com/findify/findify-magento)